# Why does it enter the same id in the database instead of entering one by one each?

Tags: php, jquery

Hy,
I want to ban a user when the admin clicks on "bannir" (this will collect the id of the user and put "banned" at 1 in the database)

to print the user informations I'm using a while loop, but when I try to collect the id of the user where in the html tag with the class "idUser", it is always sending the first id and I don't know why..

[image of membership area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otGrS.jpg)

```
<div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Admin</th>
      <th>Banni</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php while($userInfo = $req->fetch()){?>
    <tr>
      <td class="idUser"><?= $userInfo['id_user'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $userInfo['last_name'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $userInfo['first_name'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $userInfo['email'] ?></td>
      <td><?php if($userInfo['admin'] == 1){ ?>  
          <img src="../img/ok.png">
        <?php } else { ?> 
          <img src="../img/no.png">
          <?php } ?></td>
      <td><?php if($userInfo['banned'] == 1){ ?> 
        <strong style="color:#E04949;">OUI</strong>
        <?php } else { ?> 
        <strong style="color:#6AC259;">NON</strong>
          <?php } ?></td>
      <td><a href="#">Modifier</a> | <a href="#" class="banMemberJquery"><?php if($userInfo["banned"] == 0){ ?> Bannir <?php }else{ ?> Débannir <?php } ?></a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.banMemberJquery').click(function(){

  var idUser = $( ".idUser" ).html();

  alert('Utilisateur Numero ' + idUser + ' banni avec succès.');

  $.ajax({
  url:"banMemberRequest.php",
  data:'idUser='+idUser,

  }).done(function(data){

  $('#result').html(data); 
});


});
```

PS : When I click on "bannir", the request in the file "banMemberRequest.php" is working correctly.

Thank's in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all `.idUser` elements. Calling `html()` on that will only read the HTML of the *first* one in that collection.

To fix this you need to use DOM traversal to find only the `.idUser` element which is related to the `.banMemberJquery` element which was clicked. To do that you can use `closest()` and `find()`, like this:

```
$('.banMemberJquery').click(function() {
  var idUser = $(this).closest('tr').find('.idUser').text(); // note text(), not html()

  $.ajax({
    url: 'banMemberRequest.php',
    data: { idUser: idUser },
  }).done(function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data); 
  });
});
```